# What DLC am I missing in the Royal Edition Pack and the Royal Edition Game?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

So I got *Final Fantasy XV* on launch and since then been waiting for all the DLC to come out. About a month or so ago *Final Fantasy XV Royal Edition* came out and it seems that on PlayStation there are no longer any entries for *Final Fantasy XV*, only for the Royal Edition.

Rhe Royal Edition says it has new content and all the DLC released,

[image: Final Fantasy Royal Edition Description]

but when you go to the Add-ons section for the game it has all the DLC from the original game there.

[image: Royal Edition Addons on Game Page] [image: Royal Edition Addons List]

What DLC do I still to get after getting:

- the Royal Edition Pack for the original *Final Fantasy XV*
- *Final Fantasy XV Royal Edition*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bear in mind, Final Fantasy XV Royal Edition and the Royal Pack are two separate things.

FFXV Royal Edition / FFXV Windows Edition comes with:

- Final Fantasy XV
- The game's season pass

  - Episode Gladiolus
  - Episode Prompto
  - Episode Ignis
  - The Comrades Multiplayer expansion
  - FFXV Booster Pack+
  - FFXV Holiday Pack+
- "Over a dozen" bonus items, which according to description of the Windows Edition are:

  - [Weapon] Masamune (FFXV Original Model)
  - [Weapon] Mage Mashers (FFIX Model)
  - [Weapon] Blazefire Saber XV (FFXV Original Color)
  - [Weapon] Gae Bolg (FFXIV Model)
  - [Regalia Coloring] Platinum Leviathan
  - [Regalia Coloring] 16-Bit Buddies
  - [Regalia Coloring] Cindymobile
  - [Regalia Coloring] Gold Chocobo
  - [Outfit] Royal Raiment
  - [Item] Travel Pack
  - [Item] Camera Kit
  - [Item] Angler Set
  - [Item] Gourmand Set
- A number of new features to the game:

  - Insomnia City Ruins – new map leading straight to the game's climactic end
  - First-Person View – mode allowing players to see Eos through Noctis's eyes
  - Armiger Unleashed – after you collect all 13 royal arms, a more action-oriented mode of the Armiger is unlocked
  - Royal Vessel – the boat from FFXV is now a controllable vehicle. The same body of water (between Cape Caem and Altissia) can now be freely explored.
  - Regalia Type-D – new acquisition and enhancement quests
  - Additional Achievements/Trophies

It has an MSRP of $49.99 USD.

FFXV Royal Pack is a DLC for the original version of the game that **only** includes the new features and has an MSRP of $14.99 USD.